# asp.net mvc 2 remembering my data between posts (unwanted)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

i have a post method like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Activatecard(ActivateCardViewModel model)
```

i then do things, and at the end of the method i do this

```
ActivateCardViewModel m = new ActivateCardViewModel();
m.Currency = partner.DefaultCurrency;
m.ActivateAmountCents = "00";
return View(m);
```

so, what i expected, was that the view was rendered with this new ActivateCardViewModel  object, and the 2 properties filled (and shown in the view). 
(in the get i do the same, and it does work there)

but, as you might guess right now :) it doesn't!

it remembers (shows) everything from the posted object (model).

i hope it's by design, and someone can tell me why....

EDIT

when i post 56 cents and i put, as shown in the code, 00 cents in the new object, it still shows the 56 cents, thus it looks at it is right ignoring my new 'm' variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using HtmlHelpers?

If the ModelState contains a key for the same name as any HtmlHelper form fields the HtmlHelpers will use the ModelState value before using the Models value.  The only way to reset this is to adjust ModelState entries.

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

Comment: yeah, i do use that `(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CardNumber)`. and no, i did not know that. do i have to reset field by field, or can i set the modelstate to null or something similar?

Comment: Sounds like jfar has explained the design.  Perhaps a better way to fix the issue than resetting modelstate though would be to return a RedirectToAction to another action method, that returns the view with the default model you want?

Comment: yeah, i thought about redirecting to the GET, bu the the viewdata gets lost and i want to show the user a short 'your data is saved' message. And i didn't want to go passsing that data from the post method to the get method

Comment: @jfar's explains the why - herewith is the how `ModelState.Clear();`

Comment: This bites everybody, I swear I answer this or see it every week.  Thanks @Ahmad.

Answer (score 1):

@michael: You can use TempData dictionary. TempData dictionary persists data between various action calls.

This MSDN links explain more about TempData 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx